# jQueryUI Datepicker not displayed properly in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Since input type=date is not supported in a few browsers, I am using jquery UI for displaying a datepicker for such browsers. This is my code:

```
    if ($('.date-field').prop('type') != "date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
        $("input[type='date']").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            changeMonth: true, 
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange:  '-100:-0'
        });
    }
```

It works in IE but this is how it looks in safari

[image]

Please help me out with this.

Comment: jQueryUI has not been in development for many years. I've had to provide some of my own CSS to fix it up on older projects. You might need to do the same or select a more modern plugin.

Comment: This *only* happens in Safari?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example